# An error upon trying to execute Drupal Console

Tags: 8, console

I installed Drupal 8 into on my localhost, working under Windows 7 with OpenServer.
After it I tried to install Drupal Console using Composer.
Namely, this way

```
composer require drupal/console:~1.0 --prefer-dist --optimize-autoloader
```

It installed without errors. 
But when I'm trying to execute Drupal Console (with command "drupal"), there is an error on the console:

```
Fatal error: Cannot use Drupal\Console\Core\Bootstrap\DrupalConsoleCore as DrupalConsoleCore because the name is already in use in D:\OpenServer\domains\palomniki.local\vendor\drupal\console\src\Bootstrap\Drupal.php on line 11
```

Could you clarify me, how to solve this problem ?

Frankly speaking, I managed to find answers of the error, where they advice to reinstall Drupal Console, but I don't know what they means. I tried to do remove this package, then to reinstall it, but I wasn't able to fix the error.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal console global executable is not at the same version as your current project

go outside any drupal project and 
and execute: drupal self-update

Answer (score 0):

Run "drupal self-update" as administrator or whatever the windows equivalent to sudo is.